# YouTube API V3 search:list attribute error

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

On YouTube API V3 search:list page, I try simple request with videoEmbeddable attribute to true.

It generates "Error 400, Invalid combination of search filters and/or restrictions.".

This parameter seems to be not supported and videoSyndicated too.

Is the API reference not up to date ?

URL: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list

Answer (score 0):

Since the search is unified (returns videos, playlists, channels in response) you should filter [type](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list#type) = video while using video filters like videoEmbeddable.

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&type=video&videoEmbeddable=true&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```